# Error al installar pgadmin4 en Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6

Tags: pgadmin

Tengo instalado Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6 en una maquina virtual con Virtual Box, ya instale Epel, tambien tengo instalado Pip e instale Flask, pero al tratar de instalar PgAdmin

yum install pgadmin4

al final siempre me aparecen los siguientes errores

Error: Paquete: pgadmin4-python-flask-principal-0.4.0-14.rhel7.1.noarch (pgdg11)

```
   Necesita: python-flask
```

Error: Paquete: pgadmin4-web-4.3-1.rhel7.noarch (pgdg10)

```
   Necesita: mod_wsgi
```

Error: Paquete: pgadmin4-python-flask-principal-0.4.0-14.rhel7.1.noarch (pgdg11)

```
   Necesita: python-blinker
```

Error: Paquete: pgadmin4-python-jinja2-2.8-9.rhel7.1.noarch (pgdg11)

```
   Necesita: python-markupsafe
```

Error: Paquete: pgadmin4-web-4.3-1.rhel7.noarch (pgdg10)

```
   Necesita: httpd
```

Error: Paquete: pgadmin4-python-alembic-0.9.7-3.rhel7.1.noarch (pgdg11)

```
   Necesita: python-mako
```

Error: Paquete: python-paramiko-2.1.1-0.10.el7.noarch (epel)

```
   Necesita: python2-pyasn1
```

Error: Paquete: python-paramiko-2.1.1-0.10.el7.noarch (epel)

```
   Necesita: python-cryptography
```

Error: Paquete: pgadmin4-python-jinja2-2.8-9.rhel7.1.noarch (pgdg11)

```
   Necesita: python-babel >= 0.8
```

He intentado con las bases de datos PostgreSql desde la version 9.5 hasta la 11 y siempre con los mismos resultados

Como puedo instalar esas dependencias?

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer ya encontre la solucion, parece que muchas de estas dependencias son parte de una version anterior de pgadmin, lo que hice fue ejecutar la siguiente linea:

> yum install pgadmin3

Con esto se instalan casi todas las librerias exepto

> python-flask

despues instale Flask (mediante el uso de PIP) con el siguiente tutorial

[Como instalar Phyton-Flask en Red Hat Linux Enterprise](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-install-python-flask-on-red-hat-enterprise)

pero aun me marcaba:

> Error: Paquete:
> pgadmin4-python-flask-principal-0.4.0-14.rhel7.1.noarch (pgdg10)
>
> ```
>    Necesita: python-flask
> ```

Despues modifique el archivo de configuracion "search-disabled-repos.conf":

> vi /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf

cambiando la bandera "notify_only=1" a "notify_only=0" con esto al momento de hacer la instalacion, automaticamente se encarga de jalar las dependencias faltantes al momento de ejecutar

> yum install pgadmin4 -y

Y listo finalmente quedo instalado